# Hibernate integration with spring oauth 2.0 future releases

Tags: spring-oauth2

I am working on a project which is leveraging spring-security OAuth 2.0 component for authentication/authorization management. The default persistence service is written with spring's JDBC template. Just wanted to know if there is any plan on spring's OAuth 2.0 future releases to have an hibernate version of those services?

Thanks !